# What is better interfaces or classes to intercept API data in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, interface

I have an API that returns JSON data.

The returned data is not structured as I want so I have to change it.

```
{  
   "@odata.context":"xxxxxx",
   "id":"xxxxxxxx",
   "businessPhones":[  

   ],
   "displayName":"name",
   "givenName":"pseudo",
   "jobTitle":null,
   "mail":"hamza@mail.co",
   "mobilePhone":null,
   "officeLocation":null,
   "preferredLanguage":"fr-FR",
   "surname":"Hadda",
   "userPrincipalName":"hamza@mail.co"
}
```

Here's my interface

```
export interface UserInfos {
    odataContext: string;
    id: string;
    businessPhonesNumbers: any[];
    fullName: string;
    givenName: string;
    jobTitle: any;
    mail: string;
    mobilePhoneNumber: any;
    office: any;
    Language: string;
    surname: string;
    userPrincipalName: string;
}
```

I would like to know what is the well optimized way to intercept data and place is in my object. Should I create a class and pass API response in the constructor to strucrure my data or is it possible to do it with TS interfaces?

Comment: Interfaces just *describe* things, they do not exist in the compiled JS and therefore cannot do any casting or conversion. You will have to write that logic yourself. A class constructor that takes the raw payload is one option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a single place when JSON data is being converted to the App data. Depends on your App architecture it may be for example some user component, user service or user model. Speaking of services, I see this logic as a part of UserService (where the App deals with all User functionality) or even UserInfoService (a sub-service for handling only UserInfo stuff). Skipping user-component approach I would like to draft some thoughts on user-model approach (personally I like heavy models):

**user-info.interface.ts**

```
export interface IUserInfo {
  odataContext: string;
  id: string;
  businessPhoneNumbers: any[];
  // ...
}

export interface IUserInfoJson {
  '@odata.context': string;
  'id': string,
  'businessPhones': any[],
   // ...
}
```

**user-info.class.ts**

```
import { IUserInfo, IUserInfoJson } from './user-info.interface.ts';

export class UserInfo implements IUserInfo {

  // JSON specific properties
  odataContext: string;
  id: string;
  businessPhoneNumbers: any[];
  // ...

  // other properties
  fromJsonObj: boolean;

  constructor(userInfoJson: IUserInfoJson) {  
    const isObj = userInfoJson && typeof userInfoJson === 'object' && userInfoJson.constructor === Object;
    this.fromJsonObj = isObj;

    // JSON mapping
    this.odataContext = isObj ? userInfoJson['@odata.context'] : '';
    this.id = uisObj ? serInfoJson['id'] : '';
    this.businessPhoneNumbers = this.parseBusinessPhoneNumbers(userInfoJson);
    // ...
  }

  parseBusinessPhoneNumbers(userInfoJson: IUserInfoJson): any[] {
    return this.fromJsonObj && userInfoJson['businessPhones'] && userInfoJson['businessPhones'].length
      ? userInfoJson['businessPhones'].map(...)
      : [];
  }

}
```

And then

```
const userData = new UserInfo(<IUserInfoJson>response);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation !

Comment: Right after class definition why we rewrite interface properties while we have already defined them ?

Answer (score 0):

Following @jonrsharpe comment, I will add that if you interact with an API, I would suggest to follow the ["Model-Adapter Pattern"](https://dev.to/florimondmanca/consuming-apis-in-angular--the-model-adapter-pattern-3fk5).

In essence, you create a [Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) (Decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently), and you use it to create any instance of the desired model in your application.

You can read more about the motivation here: 
https://dev.to/florimondmanca/consuming-apis-in-angular--the-model-adapter-pattern-3fk5

Comment: Nice article, I would like to know in case where my API returns items name not conventional  for example `@odata.context` how should I adapt my model ?